# Empty table query against Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Table Storage. When I query a table that is empty with parameters other than PartitionKey and RowKey involved, I get an exception.  When I have at least one row, the exception doesn't appear.  If I query the empty table with just PartitionKey and RowKey, it is OK.

I certainly do not want to make an extra round trip to test if the table is empty.  How do people normally solve this problem?  Is there a performant way to quickly check if the table is empty?

I am using the development storage, as I just saw there are reported errors in this scenario with the development storage and the error goes away in production.  However, I do not want to keep customized code just for development storage, is there a good way to get around this, so I could have the same code running local as well as in production cloud environment?

Comment: I share your pain - this is a total PITA - it should be a lot easier to work with!!!  I'm just disabling my local tests because I CANT STAND IT ANY MORE!

Comment: In response to your edit-note: I use a real storage account for testing, it's really cheap so I don't mind and it behaves 100% as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got this around by setting [DataServiceContext.IgnoreResoureNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoreresourcenotfoundexception.aspx) property to true.  Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't ever get the IgnoreResourceNotFoundException to work and punted it.  Took a 'naughty' route and just exception trapped for an empty table.  Snip  below, enjoy...

```html
CloudTableClient _tableClient = OurStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable _table = _tableClient.GetTableReference( "customers" );

TableQuery<CustomerEntity> _query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
var _result = _table.ExecuteQuery( _query );

StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
try
{ 
 _sb.AppendLine("Begin listing customers....<br/>");
 foreach ( CustomerEntity _customer in _result )
 {
  _sb.AppendFormat( "{0} {1} - {2} - {3}<br/>", _customer.PartitionKey, _customer.RowKey, _customer.Email, _customer.PhoneNumber );
 }
 _sb.AppendLine("End listing customers....<br/>");
}
catch ( System.NullReferenceException _nullEx )
{ 
 _sb.Append( System.DateTime.Now.ToString() );
 _sb.AppendLine( ": no customer entries found<br/>" );
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( _nullEx.ToString());
 // _sb.AppendLine( _nullEx.ToString() );
}
catch (Exception _ex)
{
 _sb.AppendLine("unkown exception thrown, good luck<br/>");
 _sb.AppendLine( _ex.ToString() );
}

Label_Output.Text = _sb.ToString();
```